# What is the best option for remote enabling generator for solar system?

Tags: generator, solar

My home is solar powered with outback system components. What I'd like to do is be able to monitor using a Mate3 and automatically charge the batteries over wifi utilizing a remote start generator. I can't seem to find any remote start home standby generators. Am I right or failing to google correctly? Is there another option here to charge my batteries automatically? Looking for ideas.

Comment: Your problem is likely that of looking at "home standby generators" (3600 rpm, short-life, gasoline powered) rather than prime power generators. When I thought I was going to end up off-grid, I ended up discovering low-speed diesel generators for the boat market as being a lot more suitable for that use than the stuff you're going to find at a big-box store.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. It your house is solar powered, why aren't the solar cells recharging the battery during the day?

Comment: In my area, the reason is November, and sometimes November right through December, where short days and typically overcast means that having enough solar capacity to recharge the banks then would involve a gigantic waste of capacity (off-grid, note) the rest of the year, so a blended approach is more usual. The smart approach is to use a liquid-cooled generator so that heat recovery co-generation can be done to get the most use out of the fuel. I suppose you *could* have an aluminum smelter or electric kiln that you only ran in summertime...

Comment: Lots of options for a battery monitor that will auto-start a generator. Skip the WiFi bit and let a system take care of itself.

Comment: @Ecnerwal got it. I live in Montana. Winters are long, days are short.

Comment: @JonCuster - can you elaborate for me? I'm not sure what I'm looking for. For more information, I'm using propane as my fuel source.

Comment: I Googled “battery monitor generator start” and got lots of hits. Add the “two wire start” from below and still lots of them. Likely wherever you sourced your current system could help.

Comment: Many inverters can control several external sources, like starting remote ice, check out Trace...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Get a generator with a two-wire start interface

The thing you're looking for on a generator to enable it to work with your inverter for remote/automatic start is a "two-wire start interface".  Generally speaking, Kohler and Cummins home standby generators will have it, while Generac-derived generators (Generac, Eaton, Honeywell) aside from Generac's prime power units won't.  I don't believe Briggs & Stratton or Champion supply it as an option, either; higher-end commercial generators such as Wincos should have support for this, though.